# what is the Natural Language P that combines both symbolic and statistical NLP intuition so that it can autocorrect spelling errors homonym

Tags: nlp, error-correction, spelling

I am working on way to correct spelling errors.
homonym writing errors, such as writing the word too instead of two or to, they’re instead of their, etc.  how can both symbolic and statistical NLP can be incorporated into  a program to autocorrect spelling?
Please help

Comment: Could you please clarify if the approach is to build a fresh new spell correct algorithm? If not, have you tried spacy?

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Please follow the guidelines mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)